# STS - Delete All Lines Which contain a specific keyword

Tags: eclipse, sts-springsourcetoolsuite, spring-tool-suite

There are a lot of lines in a JS file of mine which contains a call to the function customLog [ keyword: **customLog(** ]. I just want to remove all the lines from my file which contain this keyword.

STS version : 3.4.0

Any Help would be appreciated.

Answer (score 1):

Click on **Search** > **File** and type `^.*customLog\(.*\).*$` and check Regular expression checkbox.

[image]

After that click on "Replace..." button and the shown field keep empty.